# How to create and add UIButton with multiline label from code using autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

There's are a lot of links how to size a label, however there's a lack of info how to resize UIButton according to its label size. Currently, I have screen view set with autolayout (all the system constraints are added from IB) and everything works fine, but need to add dynamic content at the bottom of the screen. I need to create and add random number of buttons with random length titles. So, here's code fragment for creating and adding the buttons:

```
// Loop
  UIButton *myButton = [UIButton new];

  UIButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, previousButtonOriginY, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20);
  myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
  myButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
  myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
  [myButton setTitle:@"very long title..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

  [self.footerView addSubview:myButton];
```

The problem is the frame height of the button stays 20px but the label string is shown on three lines and so overlaps with the other button title. If I add [myButton sizeToFit] then button width is resized to fit all the text into one line and so the title goes beyond the screen.

If I add [myButton sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(320, 100)] then resize is not working at all. I know sizeToFit should not be called at all because it's not the part of autolayout, however need suggestions on that how easily to make button fit its label to screen 320 width.

I feel I need to add system constraints from code, but haven't done that before, so not sure how it should look like. I probably need a ton of constraints to be added from code in order to get this simple thing working :)

Comment: Subclass UIButton, and set the size of the label and button depending on text size.

Comment: in which version you are working ios6 or 7?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **Autolayout**, you could just use a **collection view** which better options for you to lay out elements such as buttons.

It is better able to handle layouts under rotation as well.

**Or you can use this code, it worked for me...**

For example, substitute your desired padding values here:

UIButton* myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

```
// setup some autolayout constraints here
myButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-desiredBottomPadding,
                                            -desiredRightPadding,
                                            -desiredTopPadding,
                                            -desiredLeftPadding);
```

Combined with the right autolayout constraints, you end up with an auto-resizing button which contains an image and text!

Comment: My screen contains table view and a footer view. These button will be added to the footer view. Adding a collection view to already existing table would cause a problems because both are a subclasses of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of customizations you'll need to create a subclass of UIButton. In the subclass you can add a customized label which benefits your needs. You can also override to setTitle:forState method to automatically update your customized label.