# Create a UIButton using initWithFrame or always use autolayout

Tags: ios8, uibutton, autolayout, xcode7

In the advent of Autolayout, is it still proper to create a UIButton using initWithFrame or should one always use autolayout?

Comment: I think you help full this answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955532/how-to-create-and-add-uibutton-with-multiline-label-from-code-using-autolayout?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIButton using initWithFrame